# Facebook registration

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, registration

I use Facebook registration to allow people register in my website. Is it possible to do, that after registration it would be posted in member's wall that he registered in my website?

Answer (score 5):

This might not be the answer you're looking for, but I strongly urge you not to do that. Users usually really don't like when stuff gets posted to their wall without very clear consent.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, you will need to ask user for the additional permissions like «posting to his wall» You can read about permissions [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/), also look [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) for all the process.
But as was mentioned by JacobK, it's better not to do this.

Comment: maybe you also know how to change English language to my native language for registration form?

Comment: @hey no, but i think facebook will show the dialog in a language that user set in his facebook settings.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using the Facebook Registration Plugin alone.

You will need to get an API key, and request the wall post permission, and have users authenticate with your application.